# How remove strange gaps between image splitted into parts

Tags: html, css, flexbox, background-image

I need to draw a cyclic map with CSS. It repeats itself every 8 tiles except for the opening and the last one.
So, first I want to ask you about a better way of drawing such a map if you know one.
Currently, I'm doing this using background image and by positioning each element with background position. [here is the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZICtQ.png)
You can look at the map above. It has lots of strange gaps between my span elements, and I simply can't rid of them with margin property. What do I do?

Comment: OP, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably formatted as a [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) that illustrates the problem you are having.  Based solely on the provided screenshot, there could be any number of different problems with your approach, and I think it's unlikely that anyone here will be able to produce a good answer without more information.

Comment: sry, it was my all designer's fault, going to dismiss this question